# How to parse List<Map> in android?

Tags: java, android

Im trying to store data like `associative array` in JAVA. so i took list with maps

```
List<Map> processNeedImages = null; 
int flag =0;
if(c.moveToFirst()){
    do{
         Map<String, String> map = null;
         map.put("status", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("system_url")));
         processNeedImages.add(flag++, map);
      }while(c.moveToNext());
```

I could not parse this data

```
List<Map> allImages = getData();
for (Map map:allImages){
    Log.d("listImage", String.valueOf(map.get("status")));
}
```

Even loop is iterating even once.

Comment: what is `getData()`, is it return the same as mentioned above??

Comment: function to get `List` from first part of code

Comment: does the first part of code works without any exception or error??

Comment: Yes it works with out any exception

Comment: Your list is this `processNeedImages = null;` and you are adding `processNeedImages.add(flag++, map);` like this, it must throw `java.lang.NullpointerException`..

Comment: I debugged yes throws `java.lang.NullPointerException` sorry for previous reply. how to initialize then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104764/discussion-between-elite-and-thamaraiselvam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize all variable in your code like below

```
List<Map> processNeedImages = new ArrayList<>(); 
int flag =0;
if(c.moveToFirst()){
    do{
         Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
         map.put("status", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("system_url")));
         processNeedImages.add(flag++, map);
      }while(c.moveToNext());
}
```

this will work fine.

**You should read this answer too what is [`NullPointerException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)**

Answer (score 1):

`Map<String, String> map = null`

should be replaced with

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

You are not creating a new map object. Rather you are adding the same map object everytime. although you are adding new values to the map for each cursor position but the object is only one. Hence your loop is going only one time.

Comment: I'm adding that map into List in every loop iteration

Comment: but that's the same map object. unless you do new HashMap<>() no new object will be created and you  will be working on the same map object